# Using Firebase with multiple users in an iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A number of iOS apps I develop are used in scenarios where the Organisation has a number of Drivers and the iPhone is shared between them. Each Driver has his own app credentials, logs in to the app, and is presented with his own set of data. The Firebase data is persisted as he is offline most of the day and I use `keepSynced(true)` to ensure data is up-to-date.

The problem I'm having is that once a user logs out with the Firebase method `FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()` then when a different user logs in, he sees the previous users' data. I'm guessing that because the data is persisted it is not cleared from the cache. However, I am retrieving the data by the user id so this doesn't quite explain it.

What is the best pattern to permit multiple users to use the same iOS app with Firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating multiple instances of `FIRApp`, each with a different name, using the [`+configureWithName:options:`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRApp#/c:objc(cs)FIRApp(cm)configureWithName:options:) method. Then use the different apps in [`FIRAuth +authWithApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(cm)authWithApp:) and elsewhere as needed.

I haven't actually done this and am too new to Firebase to say it's the best pattern, but it seems like it *should* work.

One thing to note from [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) is that, "On Android and iOS, Analytics are only logged for the default app." One solution might to keep the `__FIRAPP_DEFAULT` app, and then make a named app for each user type.